# Unable to populate "value" of a lightning-combobox

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-combobox

I have implemented a `lightning-combobox` using [getPicklistValues](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values), which works as expected as I can see all my picklist values. Here is my implementation:

JS:

```
@track modelValue= 'All';

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CUSTOM_OBJ})
customObjectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, {
  recordTypeId: "$customObjectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId",
  fieldApiName: MY_MODEL
})
modelPicklistValues;
```

HTML:

```
<template if:true={modelPicklistValues.data} >
      <lightning-combobox name="models" label="Models" 
         value ={modelValue} placeholder="Select" options={modelPicklistValues.data.values} 
         onchange={handleModelsChange}>
      </lightning-combobox>
</template>
```

I would need this Picklist field to be used as a Filter. So, I would like to have the first value to be 'All', thus include the `@track modelValue= 'All';` and assigned it my `lightning-combobox`.

All I could see is - Picklist field with placeholder 'Select' (as expected) and actual picklist values beneath it, but not 'All' as the first option. Is my understanding right? Can we get the first value other than what we have in the schema for the picklist values? I would need 'All' value for reapplying the filter when the user wanted to see results of all models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to assign your `modelPicklistValues.data.values` to a property in your js controller and add the All value for it to be displayed and selectable in your template.

for example:

```
this.prop = [...modelPicklistValues.data.values]
```

Comment: I am getting some typeError while trying to push 'All' value to a new property. If you don't mind, can you please share some basic code snippet? Thanks.

Comment: this.prop = [...modelPicklistValues.data.values] ?

Comment: I was able to add the values to different property, but unable to add 'All' value to this new property.

Comment: Never mind, I was able to do it by pushing the value with all the required key-values: `var allPickListVal = {"attributes":null,"label":"All","validFor":[],"value":"All"};`

Comment: Awesome, glad you were able to figure it out. hope my answer helped =P